# finding the index with the lowest sum

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, socket.io

I am using soket.io and express i am connecting to database. All i want to achieve is to find the column with the lowest SUM of all the columns. I made it work in PHP but i cant get it correct in node.js . Below is my code.

```
socket.on('getwinno'){
db.query("SELECT SUM(bet1),SUM(bet2), SUM(bet3),SUM(bet4),SUM(bet5), SUM(bet6), SUM(bet7),SUM(bet8), SUM(bet9), SUM(bet0)  FROM gamedata WHERE gmeid = ?  ",newGameid,function(err, result, fields){
  var bet1 = result['SUM(bet1)'];
  var bet2 = result['SUM(bet2)'];
  var bet3 =  result['SUM(bet3)'];
  var bet4 = result['SUM(bet4)'];
  var bet5 =  result['SUM(bet5)'];
  var bet6 =  result['SUM(bet6)'];
  var bet7 =  result['SUM(bet7)'];
  var bet8 =  result['SUM(bet8)'];
  var bet9 =  result['SUM(bet9)'];
  var bet0 =  result['SUM(bet0)'];
  var mini = Math.min(bet1,bet2,bet3,bet4,bet5,bet6,bet7,bet8,bet9,bet0);
    console.log(mini);
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {

      if( i==mini) {
          console.log(i);
        }
});
```

}

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Fix your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for loop's i is 0~9.

In order that for work you should have an array of bets

bet_array = [bet1, bet2, bet3, bet4,,,, bet0]

Then you could use the index i like this.

```
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {

      if( bet_array[i]==mini) {
          console.log(i);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tetsuya this helped.